# need to total width of rotating images

Tags: jquery, css, image-rotation

I have an effect that when you hover over this one particular area, it raises it from the bottom, rotates the images, and scrunches them together. It is supposed to emulate "fanning out" a hand of playing cards. It all works well and good except I need them to be centered. The only way I can think how to do that is to measure the farthest corner on each side, but I don't know how to do that. Anyone have any suggestions? I'm using jQuery 1.7.

Link to example: http://aws.redemptionconnect.com/redemption/play.html

Comment: Change the left position of wrapper div on hovering over cards using jquery.

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I don't know how far to set it since I can't determine the width!

Comment: but that value can greatly change based on the screen resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using javascript to calculate screen widths, it is much easier to become a little creative with margin: auto

First, give the cards a predefined left value depending on the cards position in the stack.

Then we calculate the width of `#outer-hand` wrapper. Once we have the proper width, the margin defined to auto will automatically center the cards to the desired position!

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JE7gf/

Comment: is the reason why `#outer-hand` doesn't interfere with other divs is because it had no height?

Comment: okay, real quick, i copied everything over, but it does this on my site: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c08xofb1

Comment: Hmmm weird... do have a link to the live version again?  It looks like the rotate values are being changed based on the card position

Comment: After looking back on your updates, it appears that imgs with `max-width: 100%` tags are the culprit behind the undesired behavior. Maybe look into some of the plugins you are including.

Comment: i'm not seeing a `max-width: 100%` setting

Comment: also, if you come in at the very bottom left, and kind of just move the mouse around there, it keeps bouncing up and down