# bounding box is cutting off edges of images when animating

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm animating these images being raised from the bottom of the screen and rotated. But during the animation, the parent div is hiding any overflow until the animation is complete. How can I get it to show all parts of the images throughout the animation?

Example: http://aws.redemptionconnect.com/redemption/play.html

here's my plugin:

```
$.fn.handMenu = function(){
                var config = {
                    width: 172,
                    height: 256
                }, screen = {
                    x: ($(window).width()),
                    y: ($(window).height())
                }, numChildren = this.find('.wrapper').children().length, self = this;

                function findSpacing(){ var a = (screen.x / 2) / numChildren; return (numChildren * config.width >= screen.x / 2)? a - ((config.width - a) / numChildren) : 0; }
                function resize(){
                    self.find('.wrapper').css({
                        'left': ((screen.x / 2) - ((findSpacing() == 0)? config.width * numChildren : (screen.x / 2) / 2)),
                        'width': ((findSpacing() == 0)? config.width * numChildren : screen.x / 2)
                    }).children().each(function(i){
                        $(this).css({
                            'left': (findSpacing() * i)
                        });
                    });
                }

                resize();

                $(window).resize(function(){
                    screen.x = $(window).width();
                    screen.y = $(window).height();

                    resize();
                });

                this.find('.wrapper').hoverIntent(function(){
                    var wrapper = $(this);
                    wrapper.animate({
                        'height': config.height
                    }, 700).children().each(function(i){
                        $(this).animate({'left': 50 * i}).rotate({animateTo:(i - (numChildren / 2)) * 10});
                    });
                }, function(){
                    $(this).animate({
                        'height': 50
                    }, 600).children().each(function(i){
                        $(this).animate({'left': (findSpacing() * i)}, 500).rotate({animateTo: 0});
                    });
                });
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that as you animate the height of the `.wrapper` div, the overflow becomes hidden.

By using marginBottom instead of height, the overflow remains visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/q4rDT/1/

Comment: ok, that looks good, but I have a couple of questions. why does it not fire the mouseout event when you are on the images but does when you go to the direct right of them (still within it's x coordinates)? You may need to view it on a height resolution to see what I'm talking about. the other question i actually had already posted on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194774/bounding-box-is-cutting-off-edges-of-images-when-animating

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the hover problem you described but I gave you a potential solution to the width issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194631/need-to-total-width-of-rotating-images/11197114#11197114